# Ingress host subpath to backend Spring java/kotlin service not routing

Tags: java, spring, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have an ingress service where I can curl to "/" to the UI of the project, but everything but the slash is not routing properly. Below is my last ingress service I tried.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: ingress
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: default
  creationTimestamp: "2022-11-26T15:57:15Z"
  generation: 1
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
  name: ingress-service
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "53584"
  uid: fccbcc20-e365-42cd-be29-0fff80611ddc
spec:
  rules:
  - host: project.k8s.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: project-backend
            port:
              number: 8080
        path: /api/
        pathType: Prefix
      - backend:
          service:
            name: project-backend
            port:
              number: 8080
        path: /api/general/details/
        pathType: Prefix
      - backend:
          service:
            name: project-backend
            port:
              number: 8080
        path: /api/general/
        pathType: Prefix
      - backend:
          service:
            name: project-ui
            port:
              number: 8080
        path: /
        pathType: Prefix
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: xxx.xxx.xx.x
```

The curls I try

```
curl http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx/api/general/detail -H "Host: project.k8s.com"

{"timestamp":"2022-11-27T14:29:31.899+00:00","status":404,"error":"Not Found","path":"/api/general/detail"}

curl http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx/ -H "Host: project.k8s.com" <-- The UI as expected
```

In the Spring logs I read

```
Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path '/api'
```

Which makes me think that the backend service is working correctly and in the ingress logs I see the requests being made. It is a simple backend with a controller with @RequestMapping("api/general/detail/") which I tested outside the cluster.

Am I correct? Is the backend service working correctly? Is there anything else to do than looking at the logs / output of the ingress yaml / k get all ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, but what I use for my project with Java backend:

```
- path: /api/()(.*)
  pathType: ImplementationSpecific
  backend:
    service:
      name: project-backend
      port:
        number: 8080
```

Also the problem can be with Java server. It can return 404 if you don't pass necessary params. (content-type or query param)

Comment: Interesting because with this and an annotation (nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true") I get an Nginx version of 404 not found. I interpret it as Nginx 404 cannot be found, the other output in my topicstart is then Java backend 404 not found?

Comment: It's strange. I noticed that the backend server started with path context `/api` and you tried to use a service with annotation `@RequestMapping("api/general/detail/")`. I suppose that the full url should be `/api/api/general/detail/`. Because `context path` is a prefix for all services and `RequestMapping` it's like a subpath.

Comment: Is `context path` the same on local and cluster environment?

Comment: I tried it (again) - because I already thought of this and now I get the response. I now think I maybe tried ..../detail and now I tried ..../detail/. Thanks man, solution and confirmed the theory of url vs context path!

Answer (score 0):

The fourth rule in your ingress is `path: /` with `pathType: Prefix` so I would assume all requests to that host+/, will match that rule, regardless of what comes after /

Comment: To my understanding the matching rules are designed to match to the most specific rules. So e.g. /api/detail is matching more with the /api/ prefix rule than the / prefix rule

Comment: When there are multiple rules defined in the ingress rules, the rule with the longest matching path will match/serve the request. Thus, this particular request will be served from 3rd rule which is `/api/general/`. See the doc: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#multiple-matches

Answer (score 0):

According to your rules and the request (to the backend), the request should be handled by the 3rd rule (`/api/general`). Since it has a 404 response, this would be a client side error by convention.

However I suggest you to first verify whether the particular request first hits ingress and then hit the backend correctly. You can first check ingress-nginx pod logs to identify whether the request is handled by the ingress nginx. If you find the logs, then check backend logs of your application. If you can find logs for the particular request in your backend logs too, there is nothing to at ingress/service level. All you need to do is check your backend implementation whether the requests will be served correctly for the path.

Comment: GET /api/general/detail/ HTTP/1.1" 404 119 "-" "curl/7.81.0" "-" 

backend is not logging anything and to my knowledge, it only does when it handles a succesful request. I am wondering how it fails to work in the cluster but works local

Comment: Are you sure whether the project-backend k8s service is properly deployed?

Comment: I was mixing up context path and URL, but thanks for confirming that I was doing the right steps to debug.